# deploy web role to azure from source control

Tags: c#, git, azure, tfs, github

is there a way to deploy to an azure webrole from source control.

I dont mind too much which sc system I use,  just want the deploy to occur on 'push' as in azure websites with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free [hosted TFS service](http://aka.ms/tfspreview) from Microsoft that allows you to do automatic builds and deployments of your projects from TFS into Azure whenever check-ins occur in the TFS team project.  It is really easy to setup, and takes about 10-15 minutes.  It is currently in preview so it is free.  I have a [blog post](http://aka.ms/tfsazwsvsci) and a [companion video](http://aka.ms/tfsazwsvscivid) that walks through this.

The blog post and video are for an "Azure Web Site", but the process is nearly identical for an "Azure Cloud Service" (you mentioned a Web Role).

Comment: Is this feature of promoting changes to Azure Web Sites and Azure Cloud Services still the same, this post is from 2012 so I am assuming the changes are no longer in preview, please let me know the current (2016) status of these changes? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for 'Git' Continuous Development (Push) on Cloud Services (Web/Worker Roles), Web Sites only (currently), this blog posts provides some guidance on how to automated things for Web Roles (*note dated SDK): 'Automated Build and Deployment with Windows Azure SDK 1.6'  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx

Comment: I want to use 'websites' but cant because of a strange 502 error when calling another website. I have described the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057646/502-requesting-payment-service-inside-azure-website but have had no response.

Answer (score 1):

AS Windows Azure Web Role deployment project is strictly bind to specific Packaging the project the source control you are using must be able to provide mechanism to rake your code, and package + deploy it in an accepted way. Packaging does require dependency on Windows Azure SDK tools for specific language you choose.

Based on your selection of tag C#, it seems you are using Visual Studio and TFS, you sure can create MSBUILD script to automate your build and deploy process which could run outside your development machine however within the limits of TFS. This process is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/02/23/using-msbuild-to-deploy-to-multiple-windows-azure-environments.aspx).

Also if you could Build Server 2010 with TFS you can create automated build/deploy script as described [here](http://www.koltovich.com/blog/DeployingAzureProjectFromTFS2010BuildServer.aspx) which will wrok as well.

Bottom line is you can package your application using SDK and deploy package using REST API so it is very easy to build a custom solution to build and deploy directly from any non TFS source server if you are not using one.